# how to make a form for nested paths?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

please help solve the problem. i have  nested routes:

```
  resources :users do
    resources :albums
  end
```

models:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  devise  :database_authenticatable, 
          :registerable,
          :recoverable, 
          :rememberable, 
          :trackable, 
          :validatable

  has_many :albums  
end

class Album < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
end
```

album controller:

```
  def new
    @album = Album.new
  end

  def create
    @album = Album.new(album_params)

    respond_to do |format|
      if @album.save
        format.html { redirect_to @album, notice: 'Album was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @album }
      else
        format.html { render :new }
        format.json { render json: @album.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  def set_album
    @album = Album.find(params[:id])
  end
```

views/albums/new.html.erb:

```
<%= form_for [@user, @album] do |f| %>
  <%= f.text_area :album %>
  <%= f.submit %>
<% end %>
```

routes:

```
........
..........
             user_albums GET    /users/:user_id/albums(.:format)          albums#index
                         POST   /users/:user_id/albums(.:format)          albums#create
          new_user_album GET    /users/:user_id/albums/new(.:format)      albums#new
         edit_user_album GET    /users/:user_id/albums/:id/edit(.:format) albums#edit
              user_album GET    /users/:user_id/albums/:id(.:format)      albums#show
                         PATCH  /users/:user_id/albums/:id(.:format)      albums#update
                         PUT    /users/:user_id/albums/:id(.:format)      albums#update
                         DELETE /users/:user_id/albums/:id(.:format)      albums#destroy
                   users GET    /users(.:format)                          users#index
                         POST   /users(.:format)                          users#create
                new_user GET    /users/new(.:format)                      users#new
               edit_user GET    /users/:id/edit(.:format)                 users#edit
                    user GET    /users/:id(.:format)                      users#show
                         PATCH  /users/:id(.:format)                      users#update
                         PUT    /users/:id(.:format)                      users#update
                         DELETE /users/:id(.:format)                      users#destroy
............
..........
```

in result i get follow errormessage:

> NoMethodError in Albums#new Showing
>   /home/kalinin/rails/phs/app/views/albums/_form.html.erb where line #1
>   raised: undefined method `albums_path' for
>
> ## <#:0x007fdbe06745a8>

please help make new-form

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> undefined method `albums_path'

The error is because you didn't have `@user` initialized in your controller `new` method, so `@user` is ***nil***. So ***Rails*** consider it as `<%= form_for @album %>` which triggers that error as there is no `albums_path`.

Try

```
<%= form_for [current_user, @album] do |f| %>
```